# AS3: inline way to write get and set?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, setter, getter

I was reading a tutorial and the user there was starting setters and getters like so

```
    function get f():Number;
    function set f(value:Number):void;
```

inside an interface, then saving it in the main file inside a variable

```
    var testNode:INode;
```

and referencing them as

```
    testNode.f;
```

I thought this was really handy, specially for when you have a lot of variables. Instead of having to create two functions for each private value.
However, I tried to do the same without instancing the get and set inside an interface (because I had no need for this) and I get an error saying the function doesn't have a body.

Why is that? Is there any way to write get and set in such a clean, short manner? So far I've been writing these as

```
public function get someVar():SomeClass {
   return _someVar;
}

public function set someVar(newValue:SomeClass):void {
  _someVar = newValue;
}
```

but it's a bit of a hassle when I have several private variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is just a model for your class, it does not allows you to skip the definition of a function (or a getter/setter). You must declare the getter and the setter in any class implementing your interface. What you are looking for is an extension (inheritage).

If you define a class Mother.as with a getter and a setter, the class Child.as which extends Mother.as doesn't need to redefine the getter and setter.

Furthermore, if you don't plan on writing anything else inside the getter and setter, you should use a public variable. These are less resource consuming than useless get/set.

Comment: Hi. I was taught to always set object variables as private due to it being good practice and for security reasons. Is this not correct?

Also, I am aware of how extends and interfaces work. But the tutorial I am reading ( http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2010/08/20/introduction-to-a-a-star-pathfinding-in-actionscript-3-as3-2/ ) defines an interface as I explained it, and doesn't extend a class with it. They simply instance it and refer to it as I explained never defining the function as anything other than 
 
        function get f():Number;
        function set f(value:Number):void;

Comment: You were taught right, but sometimes, you just don't need them, especially when optimization is at stake. And for the matter of implicit declaration of getter/setter in an interface, it is the first time I see that in AS3, I'm sorry...

Comment: Yeah, it's the same for me. Never seen it stated as this (or an interface used like this), but apparently it works... (tried it already). Need to figure out why it needs to be inside a variable though and if there's a way to get it out. Thanks for the input either way!

Comment: What makes you say that he has no concrete implementation class? I downloaded the source of his example and you will find a Node class that implements INode in the root source folder. It extends Movieclip

Comment: Oh! It does? My bad then. I didn't think he had omitted any class definitions in the tutorial so I coded based on what I was looking at (and for some bizarre reason if you define an interface, then save it in a variable inside the class, you can then reference the object's private variables as object.varthathastheinterface.privatevar)

I'll mark this as solved then.

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why he defines the objects as :Inode instead of :node; I'll take a look when I get home. Sorry for the mix up!